# The word "pseudonymum"

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, etymology

I am looking for a Latin word for "pseudonym".
My (Finnish–Latin–Finnish) dictionary gives the translation *pseudōnymum*.
However, this word seems to be absent in Lewis & Short, and no Latin word for "pseudonym" can be found.
The Latin Wikipedia [article](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonymum) about the word mentions sources from the 19th century.

This leads to a couple of questions:

1. How old is the Latin word *pseudonymum*?
2. What are the classical ways to say "pseudonym"?

My guess is that *pseudonymum* is too young to be classical, but I have no evidence.
I have found some ancient instances of *nomen falsum*, but I wonder if this is the only expression or the preferred one.

Partial answers are welcome if you cannot provide a full answer to both questions.

Comment: I think a Roman author would probably say something like *sub facie* or, why not, *cognomen*?

Comment: @Cerberus, I thought *cognomen* is more "additional name" than "false name". An expression like *sub facie* sounds like a decent translation in many contexts, but I don't see how to use it to refer to the concept of a pseudonym itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective ψευδώνυμος “falsely called” is good classical Greek, so one would expect the corresponding noun to be *ψευδώνυμον (neuter) “a false name”, and as such borrowable into Latin.

The Oxford English Dictionary traces “the Latinate form” pseudonymus to the 17th century.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to family names and given names, if a fourth name is taken it is either a **descriptive title.** in which case it is *agnomen, agnominis;* (e.g. Cato Censorinus)

or it is a **nick-name,** '*cognomen, cognominis.'* (Cic.)

> cognominati  ergo simus, aut cognominatae.

(cognomino  -Pliny, Suetonius)

**pseudonymus,** *m.* is listed in the  'late, uncouth, and barbaric' section of Ainsworth as a 'false name,' along with pseudomartyrs, pseudobishops, pseudodeacons, and the smelly pseudacorus. No citations.

Smith's *'Smaller English-Latin'* 1870/1936, has the following entry:

> **alias:** Phr. *Turner alias Powell,* *Turner aliter nominatus Powell.

(asterisk * means non-classical)

Comment: Hi Hugh. I am Alexander Whiteheart, Managing Director of a Hong Kong based Art and Design company. Your mastery of the Latin language is astounding. Would you be interested in being a company translator? We haven't worked out the pay scheme, but we're in discussions with other members of Stack Exchange trying to work that out. Please contact me at sovereygne@gmail.com if you're interested.